# How to dynamically define a hierarchy in a JSON, in order to use it in a OrgChart JS Library?

Tags: javascript, json, hierarchical-data, orgchart

I need to create an OrgChart which will take a JSON file locally as an input and display it as a dynamic orgchart by using javascript libraries. The problem is the JSON doesn't have a clear hierarchy defined like Id and Pid or parent-child definition which is required in most of the libraries available online. The structure of the JSON is shown below:

```
{
            "programList": [{
                "programId": "randomID1",
                "version": 1,
                "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "name": "name",
                "defaultName": "name",
                "description": "description",
                "populationId": "randomID63",
                "type": "rtype",
                "startDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "endDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "priority": "priorities",
                "dataType": "datatype",
                "links": [{
                    "programLinkId": "randomID2",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "linkURL": "location",
                    "linkType": "RULES"
                }],
                "measures": [{
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID3",
                    "createdDtTm": "2time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "2time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID4",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "2time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                },{
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID17",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "Pname",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description.",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }],
                "datasets": [],
                "ruleNamespaces": ["name"],
                "ruleFactTypes": ["TYPE"],
                "published": true,
                "requiredPrograms": [],
                "settings": {
                    "customSettings": [{
                        " Key": "KEY",
                        "value": "VALUE"
                    }]
                },
                "programGroupIds": ["randomID18"],
                "programContextToConceptMappings": [{
                    "contextId": "randomID",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID19",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID20",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID21",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID22",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID23",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID24",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID25",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID26",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID27",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID28",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }]
            }, {
                "programId": "randomID29",
                "version": 3,
                "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "name": "name",
                "defaultName": "name",
                "description": "description.",
                "defaultDescription": "description",
                "populationId": "randomID128",
                "type": "rtype",
                "startDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "endDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "priority": "priorities",
                "dataType": "datatype",
                "links": [{
                    "programLinkId": "randomID30",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "linkURL": "location",
                    "linkType": "RULES"
                }],
                "measures": [{
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID31",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID35",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description.",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                },{
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID46",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID47",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID48",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description.",
                    "defaultDescription": "description.",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "datam",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID49",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }],
                "datasets": [],
                "ruleNamespaces": ["name"],
                "ruleFactTypes": ["Types"],
                "published": true,
                "requiredPrograms": [],
                "settings": {
                    "customSettings": [{
                        " Key": "KEY",
                        "value": "VALUE"
                    }]
                },
                "programGroupIds": ["randomID50"],
                "programContextToConceptMappings": [{
                    "contextId": "randomID51",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID52",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID53",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID54",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID55",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID56",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["TMULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID57",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID58",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID59",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID60",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID61",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }]
            }, {
                "programId": "randomID62",
                "version": 2,
                "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "name": "name",
                "defaultName": "name",
                "description": "description",
                "defaultDescription": "description",
                "populationId": "6randomID129",
                "type": "rtype",
                "startDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "endDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "priority": "priorities",
                "dataType": "datatype",
                "links": [{
                    "programLinkId": "randomID121",
                    "createdDtTm": "2time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "linkURL": "location",
                    "linkType": "RULES"
                }],
                "measures": [{
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID120",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "names",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                },  {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID118",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "Tdescription",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID117",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                },  {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID106",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "Data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID105",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "Data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "Data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }],
                "datasets": [],
                "ruleNamespaces": ["name"],
                "ruleFactTypes": ["type"],
                "published": true,
                "requiredPrograms": [],
                "settings": {
                    "customSettings": [{
                        " Key": "key",
                        "value": "values"
                    }]
                },
                "programGroupIds": ["6randomID104"],
                "programContextToConceptMappings": [{
                    "contextId": "randomID103",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID102",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID101",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID100",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID99",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["NMULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID98",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID97",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }]
            }, {
                "programId": "randomID95",
                "version": 4,
                "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "name": "name",
                "defaultName": "name",
                "description": "description",
                "defaultDescription": "description",
                "populationId": "randomID96",
                "type": "rtype",
                "startDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "endDtTm": "time-stamp",
                "priority": "priorities",
                "dataType": "datatype",
                "links": [{
                    "programLinkId": "randomID94",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "linkURL": "location",
                    "linkType": "RULES"
                }],
                "measures": [{
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID93",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name0",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID92",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "Tdescription",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "0randomID91",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, 
    {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID84",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description.",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID83",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, {
                    "programMeasureId": "randomID82",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "defaultDescription": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }, 
        {
                    "programMeasureId": "arandomID72",
                    "createdDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "updatedDtTm": "time-stamp",
                    "fullyQualifiedName": "name",
                    "name": "name",
                    "defaultName": "name",
                    "description": "description",
                    "measureType": "rtype",
                    "measureEntityTypes": ["mtype"],
                    "measureOutcomeType": "BOOLEAN",
                    "pol": true,
                    "sen": false,
                    "shortDisplay": "data",
                    "defaultShortDisplay": "data",
                    "measureStratifications": []
                }],
                "datasets": [],
                "ruleNamespaces": ["name"],
                "ruleFactTypes": ["types"],
                "published": true,
                "requiredPrograms": [],
                "settings": {
                    "customSettings": [{
                        " Key": "keys",
                        "value": "values"
                    }]
                },
                "programGroupIds": ["randomID71"],
                "programContextToConceptMappings": [{
                    "contextId": "randomID130",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                },  {
                    "contextId": "7randomID66",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID65",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["MULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }, {
                    "contextId": "randomID64",
                    "contextVersion": null,
                    "conceptAliases": ["SMULTIPLE ALIASES"]
                }]
            }]
        }
```

I would be grateful to hear your suggestions on how to go about with this.

Comment: Hi Abhi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share any code that you have tried before, and what difficulties are you currently facing (i.e: error messages, etc).

Comment: I have tried passing the json locally to d3.js, balkan graph and many other javascript libraries. i haven't got any errors, just that the data doesn't parse in the format I need. The format should be an OrgChart, where the nested arrays are displayed as child nodes while the nesting nodes are displayed as their parents. As you can see, the JSON doesn't have id, pid or children defined which is why the charts can't recognize the hierarchy. When parsed, it normally shows one node which doesn't expand further.